# Can laptop parts be replaced with a different brand?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, graphics-card, compatibility

I have HP Pavilion g6. I have broadcom wireless card, and HP graphic. They both cause great problems especially on Linux, they're not supported.

I want to buy another wireless card and a Nvidia graphic card. The question is, is it possible? I think it's not possible, I don't think it is possible to replace laptop parts with another brand, I'm asking anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wireless cards are pretty generic and hp uses a few different manufacturers. There's actually a good chance that would be interchangeable with other brands. Intel or atheros and ralink are all standard in one or another model g6.
As to the graphics card it's probably built into the motherboard on a g6

Comment: You're only recourse would be if you happen to have dedicated graphics and it happens to be removable (which isn't very common unless it's an older laptop)

Answer (score 1):

The wireless NIC is rarely a source of compatibility issues. The slot itself is just a PCIe x1 connection and is vendor-neutral.

Any wireless Mini PCIe wireless NIC will work as long as the drivers are available. I'd personally just recommend an Intel Wireless-AC card.